# Why does windows 8 think my iPhone is a windows phone?

Tags: windows-8, iphone

When I plug my iPhone (4s) into my Windows 8 computer the Windows phone metro app opens (fullscreen):

[image: app screenshot]

When I click 'Learn More' it goes to the following web page http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/get-the-sync-apps. It's easier enough to close but wondering why it's happening and if there is a way to disable it.

Also note I do not have iTunes installed.

Comment: Install iTunes; that'll stop it. My guess is Windows just thinks, "ooohhh, a phone…" & in the absence of a proper default, tries to set up a Windows phone.

Comment: Ahh but I don't want iTunes.

Comment: Somebody smarter than me will know which default to poke, but iTunes will set it to 'something other than windows'. tbh, even if you don't want it for its 'tunes' facility, it does help you to keep a local, encrypted backup for your device. But your call, of course, I'm not pushing ;)